# cloud development kit Dynamodb permission for lambda to delete items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

Hello I hope you can steer me in the right direction on this question.

I am using the Amazon Web Services Cloud Development Kit.

I want to create a Lambda function to delete items from a DynamoDB table.

```js
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';

const deleteLambda = new lambda.Function(
    this,
    'deleteLambda',
    {
        functionName: 'deleteLambda',
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
        handler: 'deleteLambda.handler',
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambdas-fns'),
        memorySize: 1024
    });

const lambdaARole = new iam.Role(this, 'LambdaRole', {
    assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
});

lambdaARole.addManagedPolicy(
    iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess')
);

const tbl = new Table(this, 'TestTable', {})
```

Now I know I can use `tbl.grantReadData` to allow a lambda to read items from the table , or `tbl.grantWriteData` to allow a lambda to add items.  But I cannot find the correct syntax to allow for allowing deletion of items.

If anyone can point out what I am missing it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Granting permissions to resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html)

```js
        const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'Function', functionProps);
        const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'Table', tableProps);

        table.grant(fn, 'dynamodb:PutItem');
```

There is another full example here in the  workshop with cdk [Allow Lambda to read/write our DynamoDB table](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/40-hit-counter/600-permissions.html#allow-lambda-to-readwrite-our-dynamodb-table)

```js
        import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
        import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
        import * as dynamodb from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';

        export interface HitCounterProps {
        /** the function for which we want to count url hits **/
        downstream: lambda.Function;
        }

        export class HitCounter extends cdk.Construct {

        /** allows accessing the counter function */
        public readonly handler: lambda.Function;

        constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: HitCounterProps) {
            super(scope, id);

            const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'Hits', {
                partitionKey: { name: 'path', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING }
            });

            this.handler = new lambda.Function(this, 'HitCounterHandler', {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
            handler: 'hitcounter.handler',
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
            environment: {
                DOWNSTREAM_FUNCTION_NAME: props.downstream.functionName,
                HITS_TABLE_NAME: table.tableName
            }
            });

            // grant the lambda role read/write permissions to our table
            table.grantReadWriteData(this.handler);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so it would be    table.grant(fn, 'dynamodb:UpdateItem');

Comment: yeah, you can do it manually or you can use canned policy as in the workshop depends :)

Comment: Thanks for you help much appreciated